# Shopware 6: Cypress test - reset database failed

Tags: cypress, shopware6, shopware6-api

I try to cleanup my database with command [`cy.cleanUpPreviousState`](https://github.com/shopware/e2e-testsuite-platform/blob/f5e6403265bdef2ac401ead7d81c55d45018094b/cypress/support/commands/system-commands.js#L26):

```
// mytest.cy.js
...
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.cleanUpPreviousState()
})
...
```

the request was **response with error**:

```
CypressError
cy.request() failed trying to load:

http://my-route.dev.localhost:8005/cleanup
```

The app runs in docker container, using [shyim/shopware-docker](https://github.com/shyim/shopware-docker)

**Questions**

- What is wrong with my request/route?
- Which controller has to take this request?

Answer (score 0):

To find out what is wrong, have a log at the network tab request log.

Answering your second question: There is a special server spun up for this action. It is not a normal Shopware route.

See [in the cypress.js](https://github.com/shopware/e2e-testsuite-platform/blob/f5e6403265bdef2ac401ead7d81c55d45018094b/routes/cypress.js#L44) - it is supposed to use `psh.phar` to clean-up when this URL is called.

```
const requestedUrl = request.url;
if (requestedUrl !== "/cleanup") {
    response.end();
    return;
}

return childProcess.exec(
    `${PROJECT_ROOT}/psh.phar e2e:cleanup`,

[...]

server.listen(8005);
```

So things to check are:

1. Is that port forwarded to your docker container?
2. Are you using the development template and is `psh.phar` existing?